# TikZ \tkzFct are blank under Ubuntu

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tkz-fct

But under sharelatex they just worked fine (I might have modified some thinghs though).

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red]{2*x**2/(x**2+1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image: Imgur]

And log is here https://gist.github.com/vinz243/1fb0d049700db70e4412

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please cut down your document to the relevant portions, insert it here and omit the links to a huge document.

Comment: Well, it cannot find `main.tkzparfct.table`.

Comment: Do you have `deg(t)` inside trig functions on sharelatex?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll add one ASAP although I think a simple example provided by the docs might work.

Comment: @cfr what is it ?

Comment: OK, I updated the post

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was missing two things:

- I had to install GNUPlot (`sudo apt-get install gnuplot`)
- And enable write18 with `--shell-escape`